# SQl to select from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two table emptable1(empid,status) emptable2(empid,week)

i want to select all the empid whose status is 0 in emptable1 and from that list of empid i need to select empid whose week is 7 from the table emptable2

Please help :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not knowing your table structure in detail, but this ought to work:

```
SELECT  
    (fields)
FROM 
    dbo.emptable1 e1
INNER JOIN
    dbo.emptable2 e2 ON e1.empid = e2.empid
WHERE 
    e1.status = 0
    AND e2.week = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using join? Join the two, then do your logic implementation altogether.